# assertThat: how to invert containsString

Tags: java, hamcrest

I have an assertion that checks if a string is present in the currently selected text:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
assertThat(latest.getText(), containsString(targetString));
```

But I can't find the right way to write an assertion that checks if a string is NOT contained in the text.

I tried

```
assertThat(latest.getText(), not(containsString(targetString)));
```

but get an error

```
the method not(Matcher <String>) is undefined
```

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Is `not` an import of `org.hamcrest.Matchers.not`?

Comment: `!containsString(targetString)`

Comment: no: I tried that too, but it says 'the operator ! is undefined for the matcher type Matcher <string>'

Comment: Thank you Joe, that works indeed. I have done an upvote, since a cannot accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to me this is working and raises an error:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "qwerty";
    String contained = "ert";
    assertThat(test, not(containsString(contained)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to `AssertJ` and then use

```
assertThat(latest.getText()).doesNotContain(targetString);
```